# Can I use php to search through some files?

Tags: php, search

I'm thinking of developing a site for my university courses where students can upload their own tutorials, how to, contents etc. Generally all the files will be plain written text and posted in my site. But sometimes there will be some course material and other things need to be stored which can be in doc, docx, pdf or any similar formats. PHP can read, write, search through files but if i need to search for contents I'll be needing to search through the files as well as databases. If there are thousands of files of different sizes to search through definitely it'll be time consuming and slower. Is there any possible solution to overcome this problem?

This is just an idea. I've found pdflib which provides similar functionality but I need more. Is there any chances to index my files to make the search faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That how google search work, it index lots of files and keep index of all words, but they have lots of space to store this index. I think that they use big table as they database, I think that they open source it.

Comment: Is it your course project? Or you actually want to recreate WikiPedia or document management system like SharePoint?

Comment: Of course its open source and also community based project. The idea came when I failed to find a proper solution of a problem related to my curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sphinx. It is made for searching in millions of lines of text so those few documents will be easy.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(search_engine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've searched in google for sphinx. After some searching I found someone suggesting to convert my files to plain text and store them in my database then do some indexing. But what if I don't want to do any modification/conversion to my files. If there's no way then I'll have to go through the suggested procedure. Thanks again.